# How can I stop Vim from quitting when the last buffer is a `:help` buffer?

Tags: buffers, help-system, quit

I think there is an option that governs this behavior, but I cannot find it.

Comment: No, there is no option for that. You will need to write yourself an autocommand.

Comment: Not an answer. I run `ctrl-w H` to make help window big and good to read

Comment: [[1]] What buffer should `vim` show when quitting the last buffer , if that happens to be the help buffer ? [[2]] People are generally finding it hard to quit `vim` : When this becomes Default , it will become even more harder to quit `vim` !!

Comment: @balki or simply `:on`.